# Control volume of JLayer Player

Tags: java, audio, mp3

Hello I want to play a sound with the volume lowered. I used [jl1.0.1](https://github.com/drunken-jam/java-app/tree/master/lib/JLayer1.0.1) to make it play. Im searching how to control the volume and thats the code I used

```
    public static void playSound(String name){
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("res/Sounds/Music/" + name + ".mp3");
        player = new Player(fileInputStream);
        player.play();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(JavaLayerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Player class has a constructor with two arguments, you can call it like:

```
new Player(fileInputStream, volume);
```

Where volume is a float value. You can set it to .5 and then the volume will be at half.

You could also use the JavaFX Audio Player like this:

```
Media media = new Media(ResourceUtil.getInstance().getResource(music.getPath()).toExternalForm());
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
player.setCycleCount(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
player.setVolume(.5);
player.play();
```

Comment: yeah I know. But I don't know how to control the volume.

Comment: You want to alter it during runtime?

Comment: no just before its start. Also the player.setVolume() doesn't exists on the Player

Comment: "just before its start" -- Use the constructor.